# Make scrollbar with image as thumb HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I use [this resource](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp) to make custom scrollbars. Now, how do I make a scrollbar where the thumb is an image?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the propriety `backgorund-image` in your target webkit:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-image: url('url-image'); 
}
```